# Video autoplay not working with React. Help me?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, autoplay

I work with React and Webpack. My problem is with autoplay check my code:

```js
import React from "react";
import "../assets/styles/Components/Description.scss"
import Mafer from "../assets/static/Mafer.png"
import video from "../assets/static/VideoTS.mp4";

export default function Description() {
  return (
    <>
      <header>
        <a href="./main.html" class="logo">
          Maria<span>Fernanda</span>
        </a>
      </header>
      <div class="banner">
        <video
          src={video}
          autoplay={true}
          muted
          loop
          type="mp4"
        />
```

Webpack:

```js
{
        test: /\.mp4$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
              name: "[name].[ext]",
              outputPath: "video",
            },
          },
        ],
      },
```

Console Error
react-dom.development.js:67 Warning: Invalid DOM property `autoplay`. Did you mean `autoPlay`?
at video
at div
at Description

Comment: Did you try changing it it `autoPlay`?? If so what happened...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error, I think you should use this:

```
<video
  src={video}
  autoPlay={true}
  muted
  loop
  type="mp4"
/>
```

Here, `autoplay` is changed to `autoPlay`. Most attributes requires to be passed in a camelCase fashion in React jsx.
There are although couple exceptions, for example the data attributes **data-***

Those don't need to be passed in camelCase format. Same goes for aria attributes **aria-***

Example from React [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/accessibility.html):

```
<input
  type="text"
  aria-label={labelText}
  aria-required="true"
  onChange={onchangeHandler}
  value={inputValue}
  name="name"
/>
```